# HTML image from php force reload

Tags: php, html

I have `img` element in my html page which is getting from a php request on the server.

```
<img src="http://example.com/getImage.php?id=123" alt="">
```

I need to reload this image each time when page opens. On the server side the image will be same always. And the request URL also same.

Server php

**getImage.php**

```
<?php
$name = './img.png';
$fp = fopen($name, 'rb');

header("Content-Type: image/png");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($name));

fpassthru($fp);
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: Can you do `<img src="http://example.com/getImage.php?id=123&rnd=<php echo time(); ?>" alt="">`

Answer (score 2):

Server:

```
<img alt=""
src="http://example.com/getImage.php?id=123&rnd=<php echo time(); ?>" />
```

Client

```
<img src="empty.gif" alt=""
onload="this.src='http://example.com/getImage.php?id=123&rnd='+new Date().getTime()" />
```

Comment: Actually my server php load image as file as show in my question.

Comment: @CodeDezk - the code in your question does not tell me what you need. If you need to not cache the image, then what I posted will work